# predict.randomForest not found

Tags: r, package, random-forest

I am using R (RStudio) and the randomForest package. I used the following code:

```
rf = randomForest(y ~ x1 + x2 +...)
```

Which worked fine. Then I tried to use the `predict.randomForest` function and ran into a problem. R gave me the following message:

```
Error: could not find function "predict.randomForest"
```

When I go to the randomForest help page (`??randomForest`), it shows me that there is such a function as `predict.randomForest`, and yet I can't call it. What is going on here? I checked to see if there was an update available to the randomForest package and there is none.

Additionally, the plot.randomForest() function is not found either.

Comment: predict.randomForest is a S3 method, which the generic function predict() will use on all objects of class 'randomForest' or subclasses that inherit ''randomForest'. If you want to access the function directly for some diagnostic purpose try; myPredRFfunction <- randomForest:::predict.randomForest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use generic `plot()` and `predict()` instead,  like in this example from `?randomForest`:

```
require(randomForest)
set.seed(17)
x <- matrix(runif(5e2), 100)
y <- gl(2, 50)
myrf <- randomForest(x, y)
predict(myrf, x)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
 35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2 
 69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 
  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2 
Levels: 1 2
```

You can also have a look at `MDSplot()` with this example from same source:

```
set.seed(17)
iris.urf <- randomForest(iris[, -5])
MDSplot(iris.urf, iris$Species)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the reply